# How to delete part of a string?

Tags: javascript

How to delete part of a string in JavaScript?

I tried

```
var a = "C:\mnt\c\User\Foo\Bar";
var b = a.replace("mnt\c", "");
```

But it does not work

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character, you need to "escape" your escape character try `"mnt\\c"`

Answer (score 2):

Your search pattern doesn't include a backslash, even though it looks like it does. This is because you need to escape it.

```js
var a = "C:\\mnt\\c\\User\\Foo\\Bar";
var b = a.replace("mnt\\c", "");
console.log(b);
```

I also changed the `a` variable to escape the backslashes, though this is only because it's required in a string literal. I assume the input source is from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the `\` in the string.

```js
//var a = "C:\mnt\c\User\Foo\Bar";
var a = "C:\\mnt\\c\\User\\Foo\\Bar";
console.log(a);
var b = a.replace("mnt\\c", "");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: A bit weird stating that the code works followed by an *if you change the code*.

Comment: @E.Sundin, yeah, I just reworded my answer.

Comment: *"You just need to escape the \ in the **first** string."* - In any and all strings.

Comment: @nnnnnn, fixed it too.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to all for your help. ;-)

Comment: @JanPáv, please don't forget mark the right answer.